# ObjectId as key to another collection-Migration

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am trying to add the ObjectId as a "Foreign key" to a collection. I have the previous id to link but I am having problem with the script.

Following is the script

```
 db.users.find().forEach(function (user) {

    var cursor = db.po1.find({"owner:":  user.ID});

    cursor.forEach(function(property) {
        property.user_id = user._id;
        db.po1.save(property);
    });
});
```

The script runs but I do not get the field added to the documents of the po1 collection.
I am using mongoose for the api so I need the ObjectId. I do not want to embed the documents because of the rarity of the calls and the size of the po1 per user.

user.ID and po1.owner field are of the same type.

Thanks you for your time

Comment: Are you sure you have the key name `owner:` with the colon `:` sign? or just `owner`?

Comment: I have been lookin at that query for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment the answer.
Although save() has also been deprecated and finally the bellow script did the trick

```
db.users.find().forEach(function (user) {

    var cursor = db.views.find({"user":  user.ID});

    cursor.forEach(function(object) {
        object.userId = user._id;
        db.views1.insertOne(object);
    });
});
```

So through the innsert I created new collection and dropped previous.